# When primary Kafka Broker dies ISR doesn't expand to maintain replication

Tags: apache-kafka

I am testing the resilience of Kafka (Apache; kafka_2.12-1.1.0). What I expect is that ISR of a topic should increase it self (i.e. replicate to available node) when ever a node crashes.

I have a 3-node cluster, and created 3 brokers, 3 zoo keepers on it (1node = 1broker + 1 zookeeper) using docker (wurstmeister)
updated the below in server.properties

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
min.insync.replicas=2
default.replication.factor=3
```

I started all brokers; waited a minute; created topic with replication3, min in sync replication 2

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 172.31.31.142:2181,172.31.26.102:2181,172.31.17.252:2181  --config 'min.insync.replicas=2' --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test2
```

When I describe the topic I see the below data

```
bash-4.4# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic test2
Topic:test2     PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:min.insync.replicas=2
        Topic: test2    Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,3,1
```

So far so good, Now I start consumers; followed by producers. When the consumption is in full throttle I kill the broker #2. Now when I describe the same topic I see the below:

```
bash-4.4# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic test2
Topic:test2     PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:min.insync.replicas=2
        Topic: test2    Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,1

bash-4.4# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets
Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,3
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 3       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 1,3
    .. .. ..
```

I let the Kafka producer, consumer continue for couple of minutes; **Q1: why does Replicas still show 2 when the broker 2 is down?**

Now I added 2 more brokers to the cluster. While the producer, consumers continue I keep observing ISR; the no of ISR replicas don't increase they stick to 3,1 only. **Q2: why is ISR not increasing even though 2 more brokers are available?**.

Then i stopped the producer, consumer; waited couple of minutes; re-ran the describe command again --still the same result. **when does ISR expand its replication?. Where there are 2 more nodes available, why did ISR not replicate?**

I create my producer as follows

```
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 4);
props.put("batch.size", new Integer(args[2]));// 60384
props.put("linger.ms", new Integer(args[3]));// 1
props.put("buffer.memory", args[4]);// 33554432
props.put("bootstrap.servers", args[6]);// host:port,host:port,host:port etc
props.put("max.request.size", "10485760");// 1048576
```

and consumer as follows

```
props.put("group.id", "testgroup");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", args[2]);// 1000
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", args[3]);// 52428800
    props.put("fetch.max.bytes", args[4]);// 1048576
    props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", args[5]);// 1048576
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", args[6]);
    props.put("max.poll.records", args[7]);
    props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", "30000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
```

In a separate experiment, when I removed another broker the I started seeing errors that total in sync replications are less than the minimum required. Surprisingly in this state the producer is not blocked; but i see the error on the broker server.log. No new messages are getting enqueued. **Q4: Shouldn't producer be blocked? instead of throwing error on broker side?** or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Kafka does not auto rebalance when you add brokers. A down replica will not be reassigned unless you use the repartition tool

It's not clear what difference are between your environments, but it looks like you didn't really kill a broker if it's still listed as a leader.

if you had two brokers down with min ISR as 2, then, yes you'll see errors. The producer should still be able to reach at least one broker, though, so I don't think it'll be completely blocked unless you set the ack value to all. The errors at the broker end are more related to placing replicas

Comment: thank you, it helps. if reassignment is not done automatically, then i think we have to write some kind of tools for it!! Btw, the exceptions from the broker are propagated to producer via callbacks ithink --so we have to handle this case.

Comment: Yes, errors should always be handled rather than fire-and-forget any messages if you don't want to lose them.. And no, you don't need to write anything. That tool is included https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-4.ReassignPartitionsTool   If you pay for Confluent Enterprise, then they offer an auto-data balancer

Comment: @cricket_007 when you said even though one broker is down and minimum isr=2 still the producer will be able to reach broker. So does that mean that messages will be acknowledged and delivered to consumers ?

Comment: @Vinay I believe that depends on the value of the acks. Message acknowledgments are separate from being delivered to consumers, though, but if the leader partition gets the data, then the consumer should be able to poll it

Comment: I have acks=all and min.insync.replicas=2 in  2 node cluster and i bring the leader down but still the producer keeps sending messages and receive acks successfully from broker. This is what seems confusing to me. According to docs the producer should fail to deliver messages with exception of minimum isr  not being satisfied

Comment: @Vinay I suggest posting a new question rather than continuing in the comments

Comment: Done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664195/kafka-producer-unexpected-behaviour

Answer (score 4):

Recap of the meaning of replica: all partition replicas are replicas, even the leader one; in other words 2 replicas means you have the leader and *one* follower.

When you describe the topic, for your only partition you see: "Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,1" which means that when the topic was created the leader partition was assigned to broker 2 (the first in the replicas list), and followers where assigned to brokers 3 and 1; now the broker 2 is the "preferred leader" for that partition.

This assignment is not going to change from itself (the leader may change, but not the "preferred leader"), so your followers will not move to other brokers, only the leader role can be given to another in-sync replica. (There is a property auto.leader.rebalance.enable which set to true will allow the leader role to go back to the preferred leader if it is up again, otherwise the leader role will be kept by the newly elected leader.

Next time try to kill the leader broker and you will see that a new leader will be elected and used, but the "Replicas: 2,3,1" will stay.

And if you set replication-factor=3 acks=all and min.insync.replicas=2, you can produce as long as 2 replicas acknowledge the writes (the leader and one follower), but will get logs on the broker if if is not possible to maintain 3 ISRs.